# How to rename axes in Azure Log Analytics Timechart Query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have the following query that I want to change the name of the axes.  I tried the optional attributes of render, but it doesn't seem to recognize any of them.  What am I missing?

```
AzureStorage_CL
| where ResourceGroup == "rg-sdl-adw"
| where PercentClientOtherError_d > 0
| summarize AV = any(PercentClientOtherError_d) by bin(TimeGenerated, 30m) | 
render timechart with (ytitle = "Y new title")
```

Current results:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ytitle" isn't supported in Log Analytics since it uses a different rendering engine.

An [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17123) has been submitted to track it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you get your answer to this?

The axis aren't easy to edit, and the format you are constrained by are a bit restrictive, but essentially you need to rename the axes by taking your query:

```
AzureStorage_CL
| where ResourceGroup == "rg-sdl-adw"
| where PercentClientOtherError_d > 0
| summarize AV = any(PercentClientOtherError_d) by bin(TimeGenerated, 30m) 
| render timechart
```

Now add in an extra line to rename the axis  ***| project-rename NewAxisTitle = AV***  where the *NewAxisTitle* is your desired name, and the *AV* is your old name:

```
AzureStorage_CL
| where ResourceGroup == "rg-sdl-adw"
| where PercentClientOtherError_d > 0
| summarize AV = any(PercentClientOtherError_d) by bin(TimeGenerated, 30m)
| project-rename NewAxisTitle = AV
| render timechart
```

Be aware that any time you refer to the axis after the point you rename it you need to refer to it as it's new name.

Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are now some keywords available to achieve this (at least in the log analytics workspace) as [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language/blob/master/doc/renderoperator.md) from GitHub.

For example, you maybe able to say:

```
| render timechart with (title = "Your Title", xtitle= "Your X Axis Title", yaxis = "Your X Axis title")
```

Please mark this as the answer if you that agree this feature is now supported. Thank you